# Update on SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables. First one has empid and managerid, whereas the 2nd table has empid as well as other columns. However the table2 doesn't have any tuples. How do I update table2 so that for a particular manager if an empid doesn't exist then it gets added in table2 else other fields of table2 gets updated.

In short, how to update a table without any rows, using join tables.

I am using this command

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE 
SET ISGoal1='yes' 
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE 
ON EMPLOYEE_TABLE.EmployeeID = EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE.EmployeeID 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE.EmployeeID IS null.
```

but this shows no rows affected.

Comment: How about some (simplified) DDL so we can recreate the relevant parts of your DB?

Comment: can u please elaborate.?my command doesnt show an error.only it doenst update anything either. perhaps bcause it doenst have any rows in table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add missing records in `EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE` where a record exists in `EMPLOYEE_TABLE` then you need to do an `INSERT` and not an `UPDATE` on `EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE`. You can not update a record in `EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE` if it does not exist.  (I hope I am understanding your requirement correctly. :)  )

So if the goal is to add missing records then do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE (EmployeeID, ISGoal1) 
SELECT EMPLOYEE_TABLE.EmployeeID, 'yes' 
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_TABLE.EmployeeID NOT IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE.EmployeeID
   FROM EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

is your base query returning any records?

what do you get when you

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE 
ON EMPLOYEE_TABLE.EmployeeID = EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE.EmployeeID 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_GOAL_TABLE.EmployeeID IS null
```

?

Comment: yea, its returning the join of two tables with no of rows = no of rows present in table1.

Comment: ok you're trying to update the table that returns no rows! That should never work by definition. Update table2 where there are no rows in table2